# (C++ 17) Returning derived types from overridden virtual functions

Tags: c++, inheritance, c++17, overriding, virtual

I have the following situation:

```cpp
struct T {
  int i;
};

struct U : T {
  int j;
};

struct V : T {
  int k;
};

struct A {
  virtual T f() = 0;
};

struct B : A {
  U f() override { return U{0, 1}; }
};

struct C : A {
  V f() override { return V{0, 2}; }
};
```

This does not work, as the function `f` in the concrete classes is returning a type that is neither identical to the one of the virtual function that is being overridden, nor covariant. However, I would still like to have this kind of "parallel" inheritance structure, where I have a few aggregates (`U`,`V`,...) deriving from the same base aggregate `T` (remember, I'm on C++ 17), and a few classes, all deriving from the same `A`, and each dedicated to operating on a single type, but all with the same interface.

I think this is a rather standard situation but clearly the approach I am using does not match the "C++ way" (yes, I'm nowhere near a C++ expert). How do I deal with this case?

**Addendum**: of course, I guess this can be done with templates, but I was hoping there was something more straightforward than that.

**Possible solution**:
Thanks to the comments, I came up with something that does what I want, using templates, not sure if it's the best solution (I don't like the idea of working with pointers, that sounds unnecessarily low-level):

```cpp
struct base_type {
  int i;
};

struct derived1 : base_type {
  int j;
};

struct derived2 : base_type {
  int k;
};

template <typename params> struct Interface {
  inline Interface(const params &p) : p_(p) {}
  inline Interface() {}
  params p_;
  virtual params f() const = 0;
};

struct Doer : Interface<derived1> {
  using Interface::Interface;

  derived1 f() const override { return p_; }
};

int main() {
  const derived1 pars{1, 2};
  const Doer d(pars);
  const Doer e;
  d.f();
  e.f();
}
```

The idea would be that I could have another `Doer` dedicated to the other type, `derived2`, and similarly for other types. In the end, the fact that the various aggregates derive from each other is not so essential, I think I could actually remove that entirely. The essential point is that the various `Doer`s, each accepting and returning a specific type (only one each), should all derive from the same base, to be able to pass them around together.
I am afraid that the actual use case is quite a bit more convoluted and requires a non-negligible amount of math, and I probably cannot share it in any case.

Comment: Create interfaces (abstract base classes with only virtual methods), then create an instance of a class implementing said interface using std::make_unique. And return a std::unique_ptr to that interface. What you propose is quite obscure, specialy without clear constructors. I usually don't want to know my baseclasses to know what members are available (or not)

Comment: Do you need dynamic polymorphism here? If you don't, you can do this with static polymorphism. C++20 concepts would aid documenting it, but aren't required

Comment: @PepijnKramer what do you mean with ` I usually don't want to know my baseclasses to know what members are available (or not)`?

Comment: @Caleth It's true, maybe I'm over-complicating my life, maybe I should just use templates, if I understand correctly your comment.

Comment: Well now you create an U{0,1}, but to know it has two members I have to know it is derived from T which adds another member. This will be hard to maintain.
So it is better to give U an explicit constructor with two arguments.  That way if class T changes in the future your code won't break (immediately).

Comment: @agc yes. Something is `A`-like if it has a member `f()` that returns something `T`-like

Comment: If dynamic polymorphism isn't needed : Give T the constructors it needs, with `class T { public: int get_somemeaningfullnamehere( return i); private: int i;};` and derive U from that and give it its own constructors and getters. But then still returning derived classes may lead to issues (slicing).

Comment: Polymorphism is this kind of situation uses pointers.  I recommend smart pointers.

Comment: So back to basics it is :) What do you really want to do? Instead of describing how you want to solve it?

Comment: Make your `T` class polymorphic (it needs at least one `virtual` function), then use pointers. Since `U` and `V` are `T`s, it's perfectly fine to return a `U*` or a `V*` where a `T*` is expected.

Comment: This will work if the functions return a **pointer** or **reference**. Of course, that means you can't return an object directly. This is typically used in a factory which creates objects on the free store, so returning a pointer is appropriate.

Comment: What would you expect to be returned by `a->f()`, where `a` is of type `A*` but points to an  object of type `B`? Would you expect a `T` or an `U`?

Comment: Suppose you somehow magically got your example to compile. How do you imagine the caller would use this facility? Can you show an example of the calling code you envision?